# Jquery-ui resizable function not working proparly with a flexbox div

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, flexbox, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to create two `divs` where one of which is resizable and the other takes the remaining available space in the parent container which holds the two `divs`.

Using flexbox model, i placed both `divs` beside each other and gave the one on the left a with of `50%` and the one on the right `flex: 1` so it takes the available space.

I then used `jquery-ui resizable` function on the `div` by the left. But when i resize the `div` by the left, it only decreases on mouse drag and does not increase, neither does the `div` to the right decrease..

I am trying to archive something like that of codepen, with multiple resizable divs layed out vertically or horizontally

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left-div" id="resizable"></div>
   <div class="right-div">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%; // 100% of the body
    height: 100vh; // take the entire view-port height
    display: flex;
}

.left-div{
    position: relative
    width: 50%; // 100% of the parent div(wrapper)
    height: 100%;
}

.right-div{
    position: relative
    flex: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("resizable").resizable({
        handles: "e",
        autoHide: true,
        maxWidth: ""
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#resizable").resizable({
      resize: function(event, ui) {
          ui.size.height = ui.originalSize.height;
      }
    });
})
```

Check out this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/xxxRopO)

I added a function to lock the resizable along Y axis.

Also, remember to add `#` before id selector.

Comment: Thanks, it worked....i also found another solution that does it well too using another pluign see this pen https://codepen.io/rstrahl/pen/eJZQej